# How to use Ransack in navbar search form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am using Ransack with Rails 5 to search images in gallery by their descriptions. Search form is located in navbar, and Ransack gives me results only when I'm displaying images gallery page. Searching don't return any result when I display any other pages including the same navbar.

My code from _header.html.erb:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= search_form_for @q, url: search_pins_path, html: { method: :post } do |f| %>
    <%= f.search_field :description_cont, type: "text", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Search" %>

     <%= f.submit 'Search', class:"btn btn-default"%>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 before_action :set_global_search_variable

 def set_global_search_variable
  @q = Pin.ransack(params[:q])
 end
end
```

How to get results from Ransack searching during displaying any other page from the same navbar?

Comment: Do you mean it return results only when you are on pins pages?

Comment: Yes, only when I am on pin page, the search form from navbar give me no result when I am on main page, about etc

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Add to your routes:

```
  resources :pins do
   collection do
     match 'search' => 'pins#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
   end
 end
```

In application.controller:

```
before_action :set_global_search_variable

def set_global_search_variable
  @q = Pin.search(params[:q])
end

def search
 index
 render :index
end
```

And in pins controller:

```
  def index
    @pins = @q.result
  end
```

Comment: Hi I can't get this to work on my Rails 5 app. It never redirects to the index page. Any ideas? I tried putting the search-action into the my-controller but that didn't work either.